# Passing data through two steps - Custom Field Mapper and Custom Tasklet

Tags: spring-batch

This is my job configuration:

```
<batch:job id="clientesJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="renameFiles">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="sqlWriter"
                commit-interval="1" />
        </tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="renameFiles">
        <tasklet ref="fileRenamingTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="multiResourceReader"
    class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="file:c:/cvs/basecli*" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
</bean>

<bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="clienteMapper" />
            <property name="lineTokenizer" ref="tickerLineTokenizer" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean name="tickerLineTokenizer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer" />

<bean id="clienteMapper" class="com.bind.mapper.ClienteFieldSetMapper">
</bean>

<bean id="fileRenamingTasklet" class="com.bind.tasklet.FileRenamingTasklet">
    <property name="directory" value="file:c:/cvs/" />
</bean>
```

In the first step I'm reading the folder with a MultiResourceItemReader, then write it to a SQL Server.
The second one rename the files like "PROCESSFILE-{originalname}".

I thing I want to archive is in the first step there was a problem rename the file in a diferent way like "PROCESSERROR-{originalname}".
So I have to know the status of the first step in my FileRenamingTasklet.

I read about setting the data to the stepExecutionContext. But I cant access in ClienteFieldSetMapper.
I also try using listeners, but there i can't pass the data through.

For further considerations I need the file name and the status.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `fileRenamingTasklet` a [`StepExecutionListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html) and listen `step1` [`afterStep`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html#afterStep%28org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution%29) result; in [`StepExecutionListener.afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecutionListener.html#afterStep%28org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution%29) check [`stepExecution.getExitStatus()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html#getExitStatus%28%29) and you are able to rename correctly your files.

To add listener you have to modify your xml as:

```
<batch:step id="step1" next="renameFiles">
  <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="sqlWriter" commit-interval="1" />
  </tasklet>
  <listeners>
    <listener ref="fileRenamingTasklet" />
  </listeners>
</batch:step>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me out this solution, I use this as you mentioned and another work arround for the my Custom Field Mapper.